# Adding Fields to ArcGIS Server Map Service Without Original MXD?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-server

I have access to a Map Service, originally created from an MXD published to ArcGIS Server.

The MXD and service definition file are no longer available.

Is it possible to modify this service, and add new fields to a layer within it without these files?

Comment: A map document is required to publish (or republish) a map service. ArcGIS Server often squirrels away a copy of the document, and possibly the data, so you shouldn't consider the task of recovery impossible, but it may take some effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ArcGIS Server stores mxd and service definition file, when you published your Map Service.
You can find it on this path

**\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Folder_With_Service**